# Не работают Token'ы в Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token, django-cms, jwt

Переопределил базовый класс `User` на свой:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username , password = None, name = None, surname = None, birthDate = None, hometown = None):

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            name = name,
            surname = surname,
            birthDate = birthDate,
            hometown = hometown,
        )

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username , password = None, name = None, surname = None, birthDate = None, hometown = None):

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            name = name,
            surname = surname,
            birthDate = birthDate,
            hometown = hometown,
        )

        user.set_password(password)

        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    birthDate = models.DateTimeField()
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def set_admin(self):
        self.is_admin = True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.surname)

    def auth(self, login, password):
        if login == self.username and password == self.password:
            return True
        return False
```

Выводит список пользователей через `django-rest-api`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import *
from society.models import User

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Сериалайзер:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
        ]
```

Выводит список пользователей:
[image]

Но при попытке создать токен через `obtain_jwt_token` выдает следующее(хотя все данные подходят):

[image]

До этого тестировал с базовым классом и все получалось(с тем же кодом)